# Volume of $B(p, r)$ on cylinder $\mathbb{R} \times S^{n-1}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am reading p. 431 "Riemannian Geometry" by Petersen Lemma 11.4.9 that has the following claim in the proof:

Let $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, that looks like a cylinder (that is the wording, so I guess $\mathbb{R} \times S^{n-1}$). Then for $p \in M$ we must have

$\lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\text{vol} B(p, r)}{r^{n-1}} < \infty$.

Can you help me see where this comes from?

Comment: Just checking: Are you OK with the claim in an actual product cylinder?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: I tried to estimate the volume of a ball on the cylinder by $\text{vol}B(p, r) \leq \int_{-r}^r \text{vol}(S^{n-1})$. But then I get an estimation only for $\frac{\text{vol}(B(p,r))}{r^n}$.

Comment: Perhaps the author is refering to some polar decomposition as in $\Bbb R^n \simeq \Bbb R_+^* \times S^{n-1}$, where the metric is of the form $dr^2 + r^2 g_{S^{n-1}}$ and the volume of the ball of radius $r$ is proportional to $r^n$? In this case the power won't match though

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but it looks plausible to me that Petersen intends a metric having an end asymptotic to the product of a Euclidean space (of dimension at most $n-1$) and a compact manifold of dimension at least $1$. Qualitatively, the volume of a ball then grows no more rapidly than a constant times the $n-1$ power of the radius because the compact factor has bounded volume.